# Homework Question about Orbit Stabilizer Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have received this question for my homework assignment, and I'm getting stuck at the last part :)

So I've proved that $H=\{f_{m,0}\ | \ m\in\mathbb{R}_{*}\}$ is a non-normal subgroup of $A_{1}$ ( the group of affine functions, $f_{m, b}(x)=mx+b$).

I've also proved that the right cosets of $H$ are all in the form $Rt=\{f\in A_{1}\ | \ f(0)=t\}$
But, how would I go about proving that the left cosets of H are in the form $L_t=\{f\in A_{1}\ | \ f(t)=0\}$?

Also, would it be right to say that H=Stab(0)?

Let $A_{1}$ be the group of affine functions on $\mathbb{R}$. We let the group operation on $A_1$ be $\circ$, where $(f \circ g)(x) = g(f(x))$.

Comment: I formatted the post and changed few things (for example, instead of $f=mx+b$, I edited it to $f_{m, b}$ to make it consistent with the notation in the definition of $H$). Please look over the post and make sure that I have not edited anything that changes the meaning of the post in the way you intended.

Answer (score 0):

In any group, for any subgroup, if $R$ is a right coset then $L = \{g^{-1} \mid g \in R\}$ is a left coset. And vice versa. This should answer your first question.

Your question about whether $H = Stab(0)$ is the same as the question of whether it is true that $m0+b=0 \iff b=0$.